# SQL Query string replace

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

```
DECLARE @Chat varchar(100) = 'GiveSilk:[Axmeed] Amount:[10]'
,@TargetCharName varchar(32),@Amount int

SET @TargetCharName = (REPLACE(@Chat,'GiveSilk:[',''))

select  @TargetCharName
```

thats my sql query i want to select 'Axmeed' at the result  but the problem is that 'Axmeed' string is not static it becomes any text how do i select it alone ?

Comment: Which rdbms? Oracle? Sql-server?

Comment: "It becomes any text". Uhm, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Chat varchar(100) = 'GiveSilk:[Axmeed] Amount:[10]'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Chat,CHARINDEX('[',@Chat)+1,CHARINDEX(']',@Chat)-CHARINDEX('[',@Chat)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @item varchar (20)
EXEC xp_sscanf 'GiveSilk:[Axmeed] Amount:[10]', 'GiveSilk:[%s]', @item OUTPUT
SELECT SUBSTRING(@item,0,len(@item))
```

The `substring` is because "]" will be considered part of the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Regular Expressions. A CaptureGroup is what you are looking for.  For example:

```
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_CaptureGroup(
                                N'GiveSilk:[Axmeed] Amount:[10]', -- input string
                                N'GiveSilk:\[(\w+)\]', -- Regular Expression
                                1, -- Capture Group Number
                                NULL, -- Not Found Replacement
                                1, -- StartAt
                                -1, -- Length
                                N'IgnoreCase' -- RegEx Options List
                              );
```

The example makes use of the [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) library but you can always write your own SQLCLR function if you prefer.  (note: I am the author of the SQL# library, but the function noted here is available in the Free version.)